# Cordova-Angularjs App stops on iPad after many file requests

Tags: ios, angularjs, ipad, cordova

I am trying to write an iPad App with Cordova and AngularJs, which updates itself on startup. Therefore I am copying many files (js, css, images,...) when the application is out of date.

After about 400 files the iPad-App freezes, the defer events are not processed anymore. I've striped down my application and came to this test app, which basically just init the file system 10000 time in a row:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
angular.module('tablet', []).controller('StartCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$q',
    function($scope, $http, $q) {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            console.log('deviceready');
            testFileSystem($q);
        }
    }
]);

function testFileSystem($q) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var chain = defer.promise;
    defer.resolve();
    // chaining 10000 init filesystem requests    
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        chain = chain.then(startInitFileSystem($q, i));
    }
}

function startInitFileSystem($q, i) {
    return function() {
        return initFileSystem($q, i);
    }
}

function initFileSystem($q, i) {
    console.log('Init FileSystem: ' + i);
    var defer = $q.defer();
    window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, 1024 * 1024 * 1024, function(fs) {
        fileSystem = fs;
        defer.resolve();
    }, function() {
        console.log("Init FileSystem failed");
        defer.reject();
    });
    return defer.promise;
}
```

After 997 requests the app stops no defer event is triggered anymore. When debugging angularjs defer object, I can narrow down the problem to the methode:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
self.defer = function(fn, delay) {
    var timeoutId;
    outstandingRequestCount++;
    try {
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
            delete pendingDeferIds[timeoutId];
            completeOutstandingRequest(fn);
        }, delay || 0);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
    pendingDeferIds[timeoutId] = true;
    return timeoutId;
};
```

"setTimeout" is called, but not triggered when error occurs.

Could this be some kind of memory leak? Surprisingly it works if you do not use angular defer. Is there a way to clean up a defer after it is resolved?

I am using cordova plugins: device, logger and file.

Comment: Did you solve your problem ? I'm facing the same issue without any clues...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The problem is that your memory is running full cause of a leak that occurs by setTimeout on iOS devices.

You can validate this by using instruments and running the allocations instruments. Run your example on a real device and connect to the process. Run your example when you are connected. You should see an ever growing allocation graph. When you reimplement your example without using any setTimeout calls the garbage collector is clearing everything as it should. Please note the garbage collection is a little lazy and starts only after a certain amount of memory is allocated. So you need to rerun your code.

My example code added to the app object when creating a test cordova project:

```
run: function () {
    function error(err) {
        alert(err);
    }

    window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
        function tick(i) {
            return function () {
                if (i > 1000) return;
                fs.root.getDirectory(String(i), { create: true }, function () {
                    setTimeout(next(i + 1), 0); // Removing setTimeout solves the memory leak
                }, error);
            };
        }
        tick(0)();
    }, error);
}
```

Note the memory allocation stays even the function has finished processing, without setTimeout the memory is garbage collected after the process finished. I currently have no idea why this happen, but if it is really related to the setTimeout call every call in the app can cause leaks.